# Show MessageBox message and ignore invalid characters in TextBox

Tags: vb.net

I need the user to type only integer numbers in a TextBox. I already have that validation working, the problem is that I want to show a MessageBox to the user if he/she type a point, a letter, or the symbols !@#. The MessageBox is shown to the user if an invalid character is typed but the letter still appears in the TextBox, which I don't want.

Could you please help me and tell me what's wrong with my code please

```
Private Sub txtCMS_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtCMS.KeyPress
    If (e.Handled = Not IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) And Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Favor ingrese solo numeros", "Pablo Tobar says...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If       
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code:

```
Private Sub txtCMS_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtCMS.KeyPress
    If Not (IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) OrElse Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) Then
        e.Handled = True
        MessageBox.Show("Por favor, ingrese sólo números", "Pablo Tobar says...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope this can help you! Bye.

Answer (score 0):

Your test for numeric input seems to have become mixed up with the code to ignore the invalid characters. You can use `Char.IsDigit` to check that the character is a decimal digit, and you need to set `e.Handled = True` to ignore the input.

```
Private Sub txtCMS_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtCMS.KeyPress
    If Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid number")
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```